# App Store ID via Appirater different than ID from plist, and apparently random 

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, mac-app-store, appirater

I'm having an issue with grabbing the App Store ID from my plist, and using it with Appirater. I `NSLog`ged the URL that was being used when the user pushes "Rate Now", and the App Store ID is way different from the App Store ID I set in Info.plist. No idea where it is getting these numbers from -- they are a different set of 9 numbers each time. This is really strange.

The code in Appirater.m that deals with grabbing the App Store ID and using it in the link looks like this: `NSString *const kAppiraterAppIdBundleKey = @"AppStoreId";`

```
NSString *templateReviewURL = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=APP_ID";

....

+ (NSString*)appStoreAppID {

    NSString* value = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:kAppiraterAppIdBundleKey];

    NSAssert1(value, @"Error - you have not specified %@ property in your info.plist", kAppiraterAppIdBundleKey);

    return value;

}
//...

+ (void)rateApp {
    //...
    NSString *reviewURL = [templateReviewURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"APP_ID" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self appStoreAppID]]];
    //...
}
```

I added a field in the plist called "AppStoreId", and entered the 9 digit code. I made it a string type. Now, the code runs perfectly when I replace "APP_ID" with the actual 9 digit code in that iTunes link above, but when I keep it as APP_ID, I get the error "Cannot connect to the iTunes Store.", and the `NSLog` output has 9 random numbers in the link, and again, they are different each time.

This is probably an easy fix, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Good old App Pirater. I have to laugh every time I see that name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random numbers? You're using:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self appStoreAppID]]
```

where `appStoreAppID` is an `NSString`.

So you're replacing "APP_ID" with the pointer to the `NSString`, not the contents of the `NSString`.

Just use `%@` instead of `%d`.